# In Swift, how to convert a dictionary with any-type values to a JSON string

Tags: json, swift

If a dictionary is [String:String], I know how to convert it into a JSON string.

However, I am wondering if I can convert following kind of dictionary into a JSON string? and how?

```
let parameters: [String:Any] = [
    "Key" : "somekey",
    "cid" : 23,
    "timestamp" : 1732998762,
    "number": 1124,
]
```

Comment: try [String:AnyObject]

Comment: How are you going to convert a `CGPoint` to JSON?

Comment: A simple method is to convert the second value to a string using `"\(secondValue)"` and then just do whatever you're doing now. Assuming you only have simple types this may be okay for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
let parameters: [String:AnyObject] = [
    "Key" : "somekey",
    "cid" : 23,
    "timestamp" : 1732998762,
    "number": 1124,
]

do {

    let theJSONData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    let theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData,
        encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

    print(theJSONText)

} catch {

}
```